# Close client connection in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have simple Netty client/server app. in server side I check if client connect from right host or not and if it's not correct, close the client's connection. in server side I use this code:

```
@Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

        String remoteAddress = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
        if(!"/127.0.0.1:42477".equals(remoteAddress)) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush("Not correct remote address! Connection closed");
            ctx.close();
        }
        System.out.println(remoteAddress);
    }
```

and in client side this one:

```
@Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String data) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.err.println(data);
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.retain(data);
        }       
    }
```

but I can't get the message from server side in ctx.writeAndFlush() and client side shutdown with exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Соединение сброшено другой стороной(TRANSLATION: Connection reset from the other side)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:447)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

how I can close client connection in rigth way? I'm newbe in netty

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ctx.writeAndFlush` is asynchronous and therefore may return **before** the data is actually written to the channel. However, it returns a `ChannelFuture`, which lets you add a listener which will be notified when the operation is complete. To make sure the channel is closed only after the data has been written, you can do the following:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush("Not correct remote address! Connection closed")
        .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

Comment: now I get only java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException and client connection closed. But in client side I can't get the message from ctx

Comment: oh, it's working))) I must add \n at the end of my warning string. tnx for ur help